# Grouping SQL results by continous time intervals (oracle sql)

Tags: oracle10g

I have following data in the table as below and I am looking for a way to group the continuous time intervals for each id to return:

```
CREATE TABLE DUMMY
(
  ID          VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  TIME_STAMP  VARCHAR2(8 BYTE),
  NAME        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
);

SELECT ID, min(TIME_STAMP) "startDate", max(TIME_STAMP) "endDate", NAME
GROUP BY ID , NAME
```

something like

```
100 20011128 20011203 David
100 20011204 20011207 Unknown
100 20011208 20011215 David
100 20011216 20011220 Sara
```

and so on ...

ps. I have a sample script, but i don't know how to attach my file.

Hi every one here is more input:

1. There is only one record with time_stamp for a specific ID.
2. Users can be different, for example for day 1 David, day 2 unknown, day 3 David and so on.

So there is one row for every day of year for each ID but with different users.
Now, i want to see the break point, differences base on time_stamp intervals from day one 
until last day for a specific ID in day order from begin day until last day.

Query Result should be :

```
ID   NAME     MIN_DATE  MAX_DATE
100  David    20011128  20050407
100  Sara     20050408  20050417
100  David    20050418  20080416
100  Unknown  20080417  20080507
100  David    20080508  20080508
100  Unknown  20080509  20080607
100  David    20080608  20080608
100  Unknown  20080609  20080921
100  David    20080922  20080922
100  Unknown  20080923  20081231
100  David    20090101  20090405
```

thanks

Hi again, many thanks to everyone, i have solved the problem, here is the solution:

```
select id, min(time_stamp), max(time_stamp), name
from   ( select id, time_stamp, name,
                max(rn) over (order by time_stamp) grp
         from   ( select id, time_stamp, name,
                         case
                              when lag(name) over (order by time_stamp) <> name or
                                   row_number() over (order by time_stamp) = 1
                              then row_number() over (order by time_stamp)
                         end rn
                  from   dummy
                )
       )
group by id, grp, name
order by 1
```

Comment: Please delete your list of insert statements and change it with a link to a file to download the script. It will be easier to help you that way. Right now, it's impossible to understand your question. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
   ID,
   Name,
   min(time_stamp) min_date,
   max(time_stamp) max_date
from
   Dummy
group by
   Id,
   Name
```

That should work.

IF you want the date range for each Id, but all the names you can do:

```
Select
   d.Id,
   d.Name,
   dr.min_date,
   dr.max_date
from
   Dummy d

   JOIN 
      (Select
         Id,
         min(time_stamp) min_date,
         max(time_stamp) max_date
      from
         Dummy
      group by
         Id 
      ) dr
      on ( dr.Id = d.Id)
```

Comment: Hi Ron
Thanks for your answer, but this quer will return a group of distinct rows.
I could send you my script if you wish to clerify what i am looking for!?
Your query will return somthing like :

ID NAME MIN_DATE MAX_DATE

100 David 20011128 20090405
100 Sara 20050408 20050417
100 Unknown 20080417 20081231
as you see the intervals is wrong.

Comment: What interval are you looking for?  the Min/Max date of just the ID? Just the Name? Or the entire data set?

Comment: It appears like he's trying to get it broken into some kind of "week" grouping. The problem is he's not using a real pattern. 11-28 to 12-03 is 6 days, 12-04 to 12-07 is 4 days, 12-08 to 12-15 is 8 days, and 12-16 to 12-20 is 5 days. Either his example output is not very good or he's got some other criteria going on.

Comment: Quey number 2 dosen't work, i added some more info in my question.
Thanks and please for give me for my clumsy handle of this site, this is the first time i am using this site, i will get better, i promise.